# Swift CLAuthorizationStatus.AlwaysAuthorized is not defined

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager

The [documentation seems to say that](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html?hl=p#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CLAuthorizationStatus) kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways should be an acceptable return from `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()` though this:

- Does not work.
- Is inconsistent with the name of the other possible values like `.AuthorizedWhenInUse`, `.Denied` & `.Determined`.

  ```
  CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedAlways
  //'CLAuthorizationStatus.Type' does not have a member named 'AuthorizedAlways'
  CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways
  //'CLAuthorizationStatus.Type' does not have a member named 'kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways'
  ```

`.Authorized` does work and points to the same integer value as should `.AuthorizedAlways` (according to the Objective-C documentation), though, it's deprecated.

Any suggestion about a correct, not deprecated, implementation?

Comment: I've been running into this issue as well. It seems as though .AuthorizedAlways works in the XCode 6 beta (iOS 8.2), but not in the current release (< iOS 8.2).

Answer (score 3):

`.AuthorizedAlways` has replaced `.Authorized` in iOS 8.2. If you're using the 8.2 SDK or later, use `.AuthorizedAlways`. See [iOS 8.2 API Diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS82APIDiffs/modules/CoreLocation.html)